# If there is a video with src=blob:https://somesite.com/123-456-789, can I modify the page to download it?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, blob

These days when I see on a webpage there is a video, and I see the code

```html
<video src="blob:https://somesite.com/123-456-789" ...>
```

Is it theoretically possible to append an `<a ...>` tag to the page:

```html
<a href="blob:https://somesite.com/123-456-789">Download</a>
```

and be able to download it? (it is giving me an error). Or if I create another video element with that `src` and set it to be downloadable? Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the 'dowload' attribute to the anchor tag, like this :

```html
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>Try it</a>
```

It's will working fine, theorically!

Comment: it doesn't work...